# Compress string in node js and decompress swift IOS

Tags: node.js, swift

Good day

I am new to swift and I have the following doubt, I hope you can help me.

The problem I'm having is I have to compress a string in Node js API and uncompress it in Swift.
The requirement is that I have to send a string, but because of the size that has increased, I have to compress it

I did the tests with Zlib in Node Js, the string was created, but I can't decompress this string in swift, and I tried various ways in code and various libraries that I found on the web.

This is an example of the Node Js code

```
var input = "Bytes stored within a computer do not have a bit order";
var zlib = require('zlib');
compress(input)

function compress(input){
     zlib.deflate(input, (err, buffer) =>{
         if (!err){
             console.log(buffer.toString('base64'));
         }
    });
}
```

Sorry for the delay.

The first thing I tried was trying to zip and unzip the same string in swift to see if I got the same result
The first attempt I made was the Apple example
Compressing and Decompressing Data with Buffer Compression

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/compressing_and_decompressing_data_with_buffer_compression

Changed the algorithm to Zlib:

```
//SELECT A COMPRESSSION ALGORITHM
        let algorithm = COMPRESSION_ZLIB
        
        //COMPRESS THE DATA
        let compressdSize = compression_encode_buffer(destinationBuffer, sourceString.count, &sourceBuffer, sourceString.count, nil, algorithm)
        if compressdSize == 0 {
            fatalError("Encoding Failed.")
        }
```

But the string I generated was this in a Buffer
decodedDestinationBuffer: 0x0000000127800000

The second attempt I made was the following:
This type of compression generates this string
DcjBDYAwDAPAVTwLmxRiqXlQo9QFsT3c87bXnJhWMfCkew40HDqvZRZCGDJ6u/n3noYqWB8=
It is not the same as the one I mentioned at the beginning, but when trying to decompress this string with the decompress function
It does not return a result.

This code is from a past post that I read and tried to implement

```
 let sourceString = "Bytes stored within a computer do not have a bit order"
                
  var sourceBuffer = Array(sourceString.utf8)
  let destinationBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: sourceString.count)
  let algorithm = COMPRESSION_ZLIB
  let compressedSize = compression_encode_buffer(destinationBuffer, sourceString.count, &sourceBuffer, sourceString.count, nil, algorithm)
                
   if compressedSize == 0 {
      fatalError("Encoding failed.")
      }

  let encodedData = NSData(bytesNoCopy: destinationBuffer, length: compressedSize)
  let encodedStringb64 = encodedData.base64EncodedString()
                print(encodedStringb64)
                
                
//DECOMPRESS -----
                
   let dataVar = encodedStringb64
   let data: Data! = dataVar.data(using: .utf8)
   print("DecompressData:", decompress(data))
     
    }

func decompress(_ data: Data) -> String {
        print(data)
        let size = 8_000_000
        let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: size)
        
        let result = data.subdata(in: 2 ..< data.count).withUnsafeBytes ({
            let read = compression_decode_buffer(buffer, size, $0.baseAddress!.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: 1),
                                                 data.count - 2, nil, COMPRESSION_ZLIB)
            print ("Resultado:", String(decoding: Data(bytes: buffer, count:read), as: UTF8.self))
            return String(decoding: Data(bytes: buffer, count:read), as: UTF8.self)
        }) as String
        buffer.deallocate()
        return result
    }
```

If you can help me with an explanation of how I can solve this problem, I would appreciate it.

Comment: “I can't decompress this string in swift” this is not a useful diagnosis, to help you we need to see some of the attempts you’ve done, and what is happening versus what is expected.

Comment: show us the Swift code you done so far. If the libraries you have tried are relevant, then tell us about them.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez, Thank you for your quick response, I already modified my post with the code that I have tested.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine: Thank you for your quick response, I already modified my post with the code that I have tested

Answer (score 0):

I did not go through all of your code in details, but it seems to be "old" code. Try this approach:

```
let sourceString = "Bytes stored within a computer do not have a bit order"
let nsdata = sourceString.data(using: .utf8)! as NSData

// compressing
let theCompressedData: NSData = try! nsdata.compressed(using: .zlib)

// decompressing
do {
    let decompressed = try theCompressedData.decompressed(using: .zlib) as Data
    let theString = String(data: decompressed, encoding: .utf8)
    print("\n----> theString: \(theString) \n")
} catch {
    print("=====> error: \(error)")
}
```